# Has my Debian installation disabled hibernate in Windows 7, on my dual booting machine?

Tags: grub, dual-boot, windows

Installing Debian on dual boot terms has disabled hibernate in Windows 7.

The solution according to this [thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsserver2008r2general/thread/30514c1f-e83d-4c09-ac59-aaa41777e55f/#13bd36c3-262b-4861-803d-091be44eb41d) is to make use of Grub's "makeactive" option.  I don't understand.  What is the poster suggesting I should do?  I don't have to reinstall Grub do I?  Can I just edit a config file or something?

I've never had this problem before and I've made many Linux installations alongside Windows before while maintaining the hibernate function in Windows. Does anybody know why I lost it this time?

System: Deb 6 testing 32 bit, dually running with Win 7 32 bit Pro

Afterthought: one of the differences with this particular installation is I am not sure if GRUB was installed to the MBR or to the Linux partition.  A) How would I check? and B) would reinstalling GRUB to the MBR if it is not already, restore hibernate on the Windows 7 side?

Comment: Dual-boot and hibernate make a very dangerous combination.  I've had some major data-loss because I modified a filesystem in Linux then hibernated, and accidentally booted into Windows.  This problem isn't worth fixing unless you make sure you never mount Windows partitions in Linux. (or vice versa).

Comment: Really?  I didn't know.  The problem is I'm a poweruser and in fact hibernate has become so essential to me I have no way of working without it.  I routinely do research and have my work open in a prolific number of windows (20-70 browser tabs for e.g.), and I cannot practically shut down without a tremendous effort to save everything and reopen each time.  I have multiple work sessions a day and cannot leave my laptop on while I'm away from powerpoints, so hibernate has revolutionised the way I work.  I have always dual-booted and I never had this problem until my latest linux installation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me.  [See this post.](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10209598)

> Solution: In Ubuntu, use gparted (If not install, add it). On your
>   booting hard drive (usually /dev/sda), make sure that the first
>   windows partition (normally /dev/sda1) is marked as 'boot'. Close
>   gparted and restart.
>
> GRUB should work just as before (It is on the MBR, so it doesn't
>   really care), and windows will be able to put to sleep and hibernate
>   without issues.